# Asynchronous exception handling in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I've the following code using `asyncio` and `aiohttp` to make asynchronous HTTP requests.

```
import sys
import asyncio
import aiohttp

@asyncio.coroutine
def get(url):
    try:
        print('GET %s' % url)
        resp = yield from aiohttp.request('GET', url)
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception("%s has error '%s'" % (url, e))
    else:
        if resp.status >= 400:
            raise Exception("%s has error '%s: %s'" % (url, resp.status, resp.reason))

    return (yield from resp.text())

@asyncio.coroutine
def fill_data(run):
    url = 'http://www.google.com/%s' % run['name']
    run['data'] = yield from get(url)

def get_runs():
    runs = [ {'name': 'one'}, {'name': 'two'} ]
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = asyncio.wait([fill_data(r) for r in runs])
    loop.run_until_complete(task)   
    return runs

try:
    get_runs()
except Exception as e:
    print(repr(e))
    sys.exit(1)
```

For some reason, exceptions raised inside the `get` function are not caught:

```
Future/Task exception was never retrieved
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/asyncio/tasks.py", line 236, in _step
    result = coro.send(value)
  File "mwe.py", line 25, in fill_data
    run['data'] = yield from get(url)
  File "mwe.py", line 17, in get
    raise Exception("%s has error '%s: %s'" % (url, resp.status, resp.reason))
Exception: http://www.google.com/two has error '404: Not Found'
```

So, what is correct way to handle exceptions raised by coroutines?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`asyncio.wait` doesn't actually consume the `Futures` passed to it, it just waits for them to complete, and then returns the `Future` objects:

> *coroutine* **`asyncio.wait(futures, *, loop=None, timeout=None, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)`**

> Wait for the Futures and coroutine objects
> given by the sequence futures to complete. Coroutines will be wrapped
> in Tasks. Returns two sets of `Future`: (done, pending).

Until you actually `yield from`/`await` the items in the `done` list, they'll remain unconsumed. Since your program exits without consuming the futures, you see the "exception was never retrieved" messages.

For your use-case, it probably makes more sense to use [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather), which will actually consume each `Future`, and then return a single `Future` that aggregates all their results (or raises the first `Exception` thrown by a future in the input list).

```
def get_runs():
    runs = [ {'name': 'one'}, {'name': 'two'} ]
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = asyncio.gather(*[fill_data(r) for r in runs])
    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
    return runs
```

Output:

```
GET http://www.google.com/two
GET http://www.google.com/one
Exception("http://www.google.com/one has error '404: Not Found'",)
```

Note that `asyncio.gather` actually lets you customize its behavior when one of the futures raises an exception; the default behavior is to raise the first exception it hits, but it can also just return each exception object in the output list:

> **`asyncio.gather(*coros_or_futures, loop=None, return_exceptions=False)`**
>
> Return a future aggregating results from the given coroutine objects
> or futures.
>
> All futures must share the same event loop. If all the tasks are done
> successfully, the returned future’s result is the list of results (in
> the order of the original sequence, not necessarily the order of
> results arrival). **If `return_exceptions` is `True`, exceptions in the
> tasks are treated the same as successful results, and gathered in the
> result list; otherwise, the first raised exception will be immediately
> propagated to the returned future.**

Comment: Thanks for explanation, the documentation was not perfectly clear about exception handling

Comment: So how would one do it with `wait`? Is it something like `yield from asyncio.wait(...)`? Should `await asyncio.wait(...)` work too?

Comment: By the way, the same issue arises if one of the couroutine is never actually started. Happens for me with two coroutines opening some socket (manually) and try to `await <loop>.sock_recv(<socket>, <size>)`. If the socket is not switched to non-blocking (with `<socket>.setblocking()`), the second coroutine is not started and a `KeyboardInterrupt` results in "Task exception was never retrieved".

Comment: Inside async function one can't use `yield from` to resolve future or task. One should `await` instead. This was not clear for me.

Comment: thanks for providing the `return_exceptions` hint. Doing hundreds of head request I don't want an exception is thrown cause one of them is timeouted.

Answer (score 5):

To debug or "handle" exceptions in [callback](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Future.add_done_callback):

Coroutine which return some result or raise exceptions:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def async_something_entry_point(self):
    try:
        return self.real_stuff_which_throw_exceptions()
    except:
        raise Exception(some_identifier_here + ' ' + traceback.format_exc())
```

And callback:

```
def callback(self, future: asyncio.Future):
    exc = future.exception()
    if exc:
        # Handle wonderful empty TimeoutError exception
        if type(exc) == TimeoutError:
            self.logger('<Some id here> callback exception TimeoutError')
        else:
            self.logger("<Some id here> callback exception " + str(exc))

    # store your result where you want
    self.result.append(
        future.result()
    )
```