# Asyncio: Weirdness of Task exception was never retrieved

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, python-asyncio

Lets assume I have a simple code:

```
import asyncio


async def exc():
    print(1 / 0)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

loop.create_task(exc())

try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    loop.stop()
    loop.close()
```

If I run it, I get error message immediately

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<exc() done, defined at qq.py:4> exception=ZeroDivisionError('division by zero',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "qq.py", line 5, in exc
    print(1 / 0)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

But, if I change `loop.create_task(exc())` to `task = loop.create_task(exc())`

I'll get the same error message after click ctrl+c

Why does task assignment change the time of output of error?

Comment: I believe the exception is raised when there are no references left to the task.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A Exception in the Task (of underlying `asyncio.Future` to be precise) can be retrieved with `Future.exception()`. If it's not retrieved, the exception will be handled at release of the `Future` object with eventloop's [`call_exception_handler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.call_exception_handler).

So, as @dirn pointed, while the Task has reference (assigned to variable in your case) it's not going be freed, therefore `del task_future` won't be called, loop's handler won't be executed either.

Comment: By the way (although not the question), as pointed out by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30364143/4138912) to another question, using `loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(exc()))` is probably the simplest solution.