# Catch exception in asyncio.wait

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

I have an app that gets messages from a Python server through a websocket connection. If the client gets disconnected in between, the server won't be able to send messages. I want to leverage this and raise an exception when this happens in order to properly clean up without lots of errors.

```
async def status(websocket, message):
    try:
        print("\nDEBUG: "+message)
        await asyncio.wait([websocket.send(message)])
    except:
        raise Abort()
```

This function throws an error when the client gets disconnected.

```
DEBUG: Waiting for sale to start
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-79' coro=<WebSocketCommonProtocol.send() done, defined at C:\Users\321vi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py:521> exception=ConnectionClosedError('code = 1006 (connection closed abnormally [internal]), no reason')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\321vi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 827, in transfer_data
   message = await self.read_message()
  File "C:\Users\321vi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 895, in read_message
   frame = await self.read_data_frame(max_size=self.max_size)
  File "C:\Users\321vi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 971, in read_data_frame
   frame = await self.read_frame(max_size)
  File "C:\Users\321vi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 1047, in read_frame
   frame = await Frame.read(
  File "C:\Users\321vi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\websockets\framing.py", line 105, in read
   data = await reader(2)
  File "C:\Users\321vi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\streams.py", line 721, in readexactly
   raise exceptions.IncompleteReadError(incomplete, n)
asyncio.exceptions.IncompleteReadError: 0 bytes read on a total of 2 expected bytes
```

Now, I understand that this is due to improper handling of exceptions with `asyncio` as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.set_exception_handler), but I'm unable to write a proper `handler` to handle the exceptions. I did try to copy [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30364143/10837945) and make it work. But then it doesn't send any message at all. And there are surprisingly no error messages at all either. Here's my code after copy pasting

```
async def status(websocket, message):
    print("\nDEBUG: "+message)
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait([websocket.send(message)])
    assert not pending
    future, = done
    if future.exception() is websockets.ConnectionClosedError:
        raise Abort()
```

I also tried stripping off `asyncio.wait()` and using simple `websocket.send()` but that doesn't work well with this app. I'm not experienced with Python's `Future` so any help would be greatly appreciated. Technically, I might be able to use `heartbeats` to check if the connection is alive every time but that can be more network consuming so I prefer not to.

Comment: The answer shows how to do it properly, but for reference you should be aware that `future.exception()` returns an exception _object_, so the correct check would be something like `if future.exception() is websockets.ConnectionClosedError: ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are awaiting only one coroutine, do it directly and exceptions will be naturally propagated:

```
try
    print("\nDEBUG: "+message)
    await websocket.send(message)
except Exception:
    raise Abort()
```

---

There is no reason to use `asyncio.wait` which is designed to wait for several tasks. Using it for one coroutine creates lots of overhead: a new task is created, scheduled, run and finally returned in an one-element set and its result must be checked in a separate step. That is basically what the last code snippet does.

---

Simple `websocket.send(message)` (when defined with `async def`) without the `await` practically does nothing. Technically it creates a couroutine object from a coroutine function, but that couroutine is not executed.

Comment: If I don't use `asyncio.wait()`, it doesn't send any message or throw any exception. In the initial function which is run using `asyncio.get_event_loop.run_until_complete()`, simple `websocket.send()` works. When the control goes to any function outside of it, it stops sending messages.

Comment: That is a different question. Please post a minimal example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @VishalDS You need to only remove `asyncio.wait()`, but leave the `await`, so that it becomes `await websocket.send(message)`. That should certainly work.

Comment: @user4815162342 I'm already using `await websocket.send()` that's not working outside of the main function

Comment: @VishalDS And `await asyncio.wait([websocket.send(...)])` works in the exact same code? That's interesting.

Comment: @VPfB the full code is [here](https://github.com/vishal-ds/FlashGrab/blob/master/back%20end/app.py)

Comment: @user4815162342 yes that's the problem. It's driving me nuts LOL

Comment: @VishalDS  One possibility is that `asyncio.wait()` is muting an exception in the awaited coroutine, which "helps" you by hiding a different bug. Just a guess...

Comment: @VishalDS I could not reproduce the problem. I have reduced the program to just a websocket server and it accepts ws connections and communicates with a ws client. When I replaced `asyncio.wait` with plain `await` in the `status` function, nothing changed, it worked as before. One more thing: please use `except Exception:`, not just plain `except:`. Always unless there is a special reason. It makes a difference when cancelling tasks in asyncio and when prorgams are interrupted with crtl-C.

Comment: Ok thanks for trying @VPfB I'll mark your answer as correct but I'm still having the same issue

Comment: @VishalDS Thank you. You could try to create a small program to demonstrate the issue. Either you will find the problem during the process or you can then ask the SO community for help.

Comment: Could you please make one test? If `await websocket.send(...)` does not work, try `await asyncio.Task(websocket.send(...))`. The task creation is a side-effect of `asyncio.wait`. If that works, there is probably some kind of deadlock, maybe in the client-server communication (just guessing).